# can I use Google colabs with someone else?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm working with Google colabs with my friend, then in a point of the project we must work at the same time, but sometimes when we will save the project for some of us is asking or telling us that is a error, then we have to save it manually or choose what lines of code should stay or not. Then that is why I'm asking about it, or maybe we have to make some other step like a pull request

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if colab have such feature, but how about putting the colab in a github repo? That way you guys can both have your own version of the same notebook on a separate branch and when you need to have you friend's changes, you can just have him push it to the remote repo, then you can pull and merge your branch into his?